# Parsing texts with PerlRegEx in Delphi XE4

Tags: regex, delphi

I have to parse Spice file format and I chosen regular expression matching to parse the rows. For this I selected [TPerlRegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/download/TPerlRegEx.zip). I trapped by `.subckt` processing. The SubCircuit object has the following attributes : name, node name list, parameter name-value pair list. I wrote some (the possible) test cases and few of them fail. The source code:

```
uses
  PerlRegEx
  ;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aPRE : TPerlRegEx;
  i : integer;

function getMatchingCaseIndex( subject_ : string ) : integer;
const
  CONST_regexp_CubCircuitHeaders : array [0..3] of string =
    ( '.subckt\s([^\s]+)\s([\s\S]+)',
      '.subckt\s([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\s([^=]+=[^\s]+)',
      '.subckt\s([^\s]+)\s((?:[^\s]+)+)\sparams:\s([^\s]+\s[^\s]+)',
      '.subckt\s([^\s]+)\s((?:[^\s]+)+)\sparams:\s([^=]+=[^\s]+)' );
var
  i : integer;
begin
  result := -1;
  aPRE.subject := subject_;
  i := length( CONST_regexp_CubCircuitHeaders );
  while ( ( result < 0 ) and ( i > 0 ) ) do
  begin
    dec( i );
    aPRE.regEx := CONST_regexp_CubCircuitHeaders[i];
    if ( aPRE.match ) then
      result := i;
  end;
end;

begin
  aPRE := TPerlRegEx.create;
  try
    // Should return 0
    // Test cases without any parameter definition
    { 1}  i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1' );
    { 2}  i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 NODE2' );
    // Should return 1
    // Test cases when 'params:' does not inserted (name=value parameter definiion form expected)
    { 3}  i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 name1=value1' );
    { 4}  i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 name1=value1 name2=value2' );
    { 5}  i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 NODE2 name1=value1' );
    { 6}  i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 NODE2 name1=value1 name2=value2' );
    // Should return 2
    // Test cases when 'params:' inserted (name value parameter definition form)
    { 7}  i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 params: name1 value1' );
    { 8}  i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 params: name1 value1 name2 value2' );
    { 9*} i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 NODE2 params: name1 value1' );
    {10*} i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 NODE2 params: name1 value1 name2 value2' );
    // Should return 3
    // Test cases when 'params:' inserted (name=value parameter definition form)
    {11}  i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 params: name1=value1 name2=value2' );
    {12}  i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 params: name1=value1 name2=value2' );
    {13*} i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 NODE2 params: name1=value1 name2=value2' );
    {14*} i := getMatchingCaseIndex( '.subckt NAME NODE1 NODE2 params: name1=value1 name2=value2' );
  finally
    aPRE.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Test case (9,10) passes back 0 instead of 2 and test case (13,14) passes back 1 instead of 3. When two (or more) node name defined before the parameter list. How should I modify my regexps to all test cases pass back the right values?

Comment: Don't have TPerlRegEx at hand - I guess you are on a version before `System.RegularExpressions` was included? Your regexes should be fine, though `((?:[^\s]+)+)` should just be `(\S+)` and `.subckt` should probably be `\.subckt`.

Comment: @SebastianProske I use Delphi XE4. Is there a built in regexp solution inside it? I just searched for one on the net. Most of the cases I need more then one node name before the parameter lists and `(\S+)` matches just one world, doesn't it? There should be some bug in the regexps, because the function result is not the expected one. Your `\.subckt` reflection is right, thx

Comment: @SebastianProske I checked out the built in regexp implementation and it gives back the same values. (with the suggested modifications in the regexps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I modified the regexps in the following way and all of the test cases pass:

```
'\.subckt\s(\S+)\s((?:[^\s:]+\s*)+)',
'\.subckt\s(\S+)\s((?:[^\s:]+\s*)+)\s([^=]+=\S+)',
'\.subckt\s(\S+)\s((?:[^\s:]+\s*)+)\sparams:\s((?:\S+\s*)+)',
'\.subckt\s(\S+)\s((?:[^\s:]+\s*)+)\sparams:\s([^=]+=\S+)' );
```